# Error while translating dataframe using a function

Tags: python, dataframe, series, translate

I am trying to translate a script i have saved.

I have a series:

```
transcript
Out[69]: 
0                o entraremos project windows en pinyin 
1             místico en serio estás en dicho caso allí 
2               no hay ningún for cierro forzar nada en 
3                                 sí cinco interior del 
4                                   fausto ruina en mon 

159                                   soc gracias señor 
160    seguro de estar bien okay hasta la edad arias ...
161                                           la voz no 
162    tal vez no saben la intención que no comen no ...
163                                         cuál de los 


type(transcript)
Out[66]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

I want to be able to translate this

```
import goslate
gs = goslate.Goslate()

englishtext = []
for trans in transcript():
    transword = gs.translate(trans, 'en')
    englishtext.append(transword)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-68-60f24c45c582>", line 2, in <module>
    for trans in transcript():

TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

Why do I get this error? How do I resolve his?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the error is here: `for trans in transcript():`, you should remove the parentheses.  The program is trying to call `transcript` like a function